# When running grunt on Windows, I receive "Access is Denied" error with default grunt.js file

Tags: windows, gruntjs

I'm getting grunt.js setup on a Windows 7 machine. I've got Grunt setup on my `%PATH%`, but when I try to execute it, I receive this error:

```
C:\project>grunt
Access is denied.
```

However, if I rename the grunt file from `grunt.js` to `gruntfile.js` and rerun Grunt using the `--config` flag, it works:

```
C:\project>grunt --config gruntfile.js

...Lots of Grunt output...

5 specs, 0 failures in 0.041s.

Done, without errors.
```

My `%PATH%` is setup with follows:

`set PATH=.;%NODE_HOME%;%PATH%`

Any idea why I'm seeing this "Access is denied" error?

Comment: Update: This problem only exists for Grunt 0.3. With 0.4 and above, there are no naming conflicts (as it was renamed Gruntfile.js), so `grunt` will resolve to grunt.cmd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grunt's [FAQ](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/faq.md#on-windows-why-does-my-js-editor-open-when-i-try-to-run-grunt-%E2%9A%91) gives me the solution:

> If you're in the same directory as the grunt.js gruntfile, Windows
>   tries to execute that file when you type grunt. So you need to type
>   grunt.cmd instead.

The FAQ just showed a different output than what I was seeing; using `grunt.cmd` fixes it.