# Executing 'grunt' command throws 'Access is denied' error

Tags: gruntjs

I have some application which uses grunt. My application was working perfectly until yesterday. But today, when I try to execute any grunt commands, I get 'Access is denied' error. Please find the below screenshot. Not sure why is this happening. Any idea on this.?

[image]

Comment: Were you running cmd in Administrator mode?

Comment: No. I haven't used the administrator mode earlier also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When running grunt on Windows, I receive "Access is Denied" error with default grunt.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269658/when-running-grunt-on-windows-i-receive-access-is-denied-error-with-default-g)